# How to extract data from array into another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I'm using react native and I have an array that looks like:

```
[
  [
    {
      "__typename": "Todo",
      "createdAt": "2023-07-15T01:19:56.489Z",
      "description": null,
      "id": "43696aa7-3244-44a9-abd0-3437be799121",
      "name": "squat",
      "reps": 12,
      "updatedAt": "2023-07-15T01:19:56.489Z",
      "weight": 135
    },
    {
      "__typename": "Todo",
      "createdAt": "2023-07-15T13:04:32.141Z",
      "description": null,
      "id": "616e19b9-4786-4b2e-bf11-7c54bd725e4b",
      "name": "squat",
      "reps": 1,
      "updatedAt": "2023-07-15T13:04:32.141Z",
      "weight": 135
    }
  ]
]
```

I would like to get all of the "weights" from each array object into a separate array where it would look like:

```
[135, 135]
```

I tried doing `arrayname.map((b,i) => b[i].weight)` but this only gave me the first objects weight so it looked like: [135]

Any help would be appreciated. I understand this might be a dumb question but I really don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

To extract all the "weights" from each object in the array, you can use the map function to iterate over the array and access the "weight" property of each object. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```js
const data = [[{"__typename": "Todo", "createdAt": "2023-07-15T01:19:56.489Z", "description": null, "id": "43696aa7-3244-44a9-abd0-3437be799121", "name": "squat", "reps": 12, "updatedAt": "2023-07-15T01:19:56.489Z", "weight": 135}, {"__typename": "Todo", "createdAt": "2023-07-15T13:04:32.141Z", "description": null, "id": "616e19b9-4786-4b2e-bf11-7c54bd725e4b", "name": "squat", "reps": 1, "updatedAt": "2023-07-15T13:04:32.141Z", "weight": 135}]];
    
const weights = data.flatMap(innerArr => innerArr.map(obj => obj.weight));

console.log(weights); // Output: [135, 135]
```

In the code above, [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) is used to flatten the nested array into a single-level array. Then, [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is used to iterate over each object in the array and extract the "weight" property. Finally, the resulting weights are stored in the weights array.

This will give you the desired result of `[135, 135]`.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the latest policies since your answer appears likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). As a heads-up, [posting of AI-generated content is not permitted on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831).

If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Answer (score 1):

Here your items are inside the child array. You can try the following.

```
arrayName.map((arr,i) => arr.map((obj) => obj.weight)).flat();
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this:

```js
var data =[
  [
    {
      "__typename": "Todo",
      "createdAt": "2023-07-15T01:19:56.489Z",
      "description": null,
      "id": "43696aa7-3244-44a9-abd0-3437be799121",
      "name": "squat",
      "reps": 12,
      "updatedAt": "2023-07-15T01:19:56.489Z",
      "weight": 135
    },
    {
      "__typename": "Todo",
      "createdAt": "2023-07-15T13:04:32.141Z",
      "description": null,
      "id": "616e19b9-4786-4b2e-bf11-7c54bd725e4b",
      "name": "squat",
      "reps": 1,
      "updatedAt": "2023-07-15T13:04:32.141Z",
      "weight": 135
    }
  ]
];

function get_weights(_data){
  var out = [];
  for(var key in _data[0]){
    out.push(data[0][key].weight);
  }
  return out;
}

 console.log( get_weights(data));
```